# Socket.io, emit to a single client

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I have a chat app that allows multiple people to connect to a chatroom, When a new client connects to the chatroom i want to be able to show them the chat history, i've done his my emitting an chat history but obviously that updates everyone in the chat leading to duplicate messages.

How would i single out the new user and display the chat just to them?

this is the server code

```
socket.on('chat history', function(){
   console.log("Chat History");

   posts.find({chatId: chatId}).then(function(chatHistory){
     console.log("Chat history", chatHistory);
     socket.emit('chat history', chatHistory);
   })


});
```

This is the client side code

```
socket.on('chat history', function(chatHistory){
   for (var key in chatHistory) {
     var obj = chatHistory[key];
     addChatMessage(obj);
   }
});
```

I am using the socketio example, the data is sending back to this method and the add chat message updates everyone.

Comment: Server-side, emit through a single socket (`socket.emit('chat history')`), not all the sockets in the room (`io.to('some room').emit('chat history')`).

Comment: @JeremyThille Hi, could you show me this in a but more detail?

Comment: Well there's no more detail. You have one individual `socket`, then you use it to emit your message to one particular person : `socket.emit("chat history", data)`. I don't know how to say it better :) `io.on( "connection", function(socket){ socket.emit("chat history", someData); })`

Comment: @JeremyThille Hey, when i use socket.emit("chat history", data) it updates everyone in the chat.

Comment: Why are you listening for chat history on the server side? The server _sends_ the chat history to the client, it will never _receive_ it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate to an individual, you'll require to capture their ID. You can do this by accessing the `socket` object, assuming that's the name of what you're creating on the connect action as illustrated in this block of server-side code:

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {

  socket.on('chat history', async function(){
   console.log("Chat History");

   const chatHistory = await posts.find({chatId: chatId})

   console.log("Chat history", chatHistory)
   socket.to(socket.id).emit('chat history', chatHistory)
  })
})
```

In your example I've swapped the promise for async/await for the sake of readability, but you can accomplish the same using your preferred pattern. Just trust in this case that the ID which you seek to capture will always be kept to that context within the `socket` object that you generate on connection.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code line to send event/message to particular user/client:

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('chatHistory', data);
```

Comment: Might be a silly question but how do i get the socketid?

Comment: socketid can be fetched through "socket.id".  @ragebunny

Comment: But `socket` is already a particular socket/client... Your code is the same as `socket.emit()`

Comment: @mn.agg Hi, i've tried this and it doesn't seem to hit the on('chat history') on the client now. I'm assuming that i does this is the server side?